# Can XGBoost solve XOR problem?

Tags: machine-learning, problem-solving, gradient-boosting, xor-problem

I've read that decision trees are able to solve XOR operation so I conclude that XGBoost algorithm can solve it as well.

But my tests on the datasets (datasets that should be highly "xor-ish") do not produce good results, so I wanted to ask whether XGBoost is able to solve this type of problem at all, or maybe I should use a different algorithm like ANN?

**EDIT**: I found a similar question with a negative answer [here](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/is-that-possible-to-fit-a-xor-problem-with-xgboost/1794).

Could someone please confirm that XGBoost cannot perform XOR operation due to "greedy approach" and whether this can maybe be changed in parameters?